# "sprained his ankle" vs. "had his ankle sprained"

Tags: difference, experiential-have

What's the difference between the following?

> John sprained his ankle while walking downstairs.

> John had his ankle sprained while walking downstairs.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence (which uses a past participle) implies that there is some agent (besides John) that sprained his ankle. For example, if I write "I had my car washed", then most people will infer that someone (besides me) washed my car. Native English speakers, therefore, will probably prefer the first sentence.

Comment: To make the point even stronger, I'd add that in the English language, an ankle is never sprained by an outside agent. Only the person to whom the ankle belongs can sprain it. So to "have one's ankle sprained" is not only not preferred but nonexistent.

Comment: If the injury was because John tripped over something, could the second sentence be used naturally?

Comment: No,  not even if the something had been placed with the intention of causing John to trip.